# What is the Command Argument Structure for Google Chrome Application Shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts

If I want to manually create a Chrome Application Shortcut, I know that I have to point it to the Chrome executable and pass it the URL to the site.

But what argument to I pass so that it opens in an application style window instead of just opening in a new tab in my open Chrome window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using the --app="[url]" switch like so:

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app="http://www.pandora.com"
```

I would speculate that it would work the same in windows if pointed to the chrome.exe file.

You can find this command and others [here](http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html).

Comment: In Windows, I used Chrome to create an application shortcut, then looked at the shortcut properties. It does indeed use `"chromepath\chrome.exe" --app="url"`

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new chrome browser on an URL for example like that:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.atlas-informatik.ch

Answer (score -3):

Looking at [this](http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html) and [this](http://chromespot.com/forum/google-chrome-tips-and-tricks/697-chrome-exe-command-line-switches.html), it does not appear to be possible to create a new window using arguments passed to Chrome.

Comment: If you go back and look at your first link, it actually has the --app switch that I was able to use.

Comment: Yup: "Specifies that the associated value should be launched in "application" mode.
--app"